# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null

Tags: angular, filter, null

i am new on ANGULAR and  im trying to build  an application who can display the users in the database with the possibility of update or delete (the red button in the photo below) a user. 
if i have >1 user the delete button will delete this user from the database and will hide him from the page immediately , but f i  have just one user and press delete the user will be deleted from the database as well but still in the page unless i refresh the page.

users = [];

> ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();
  }
```

> ReloadData function:

```
  reloadData() {
    this.userService
      .getUsersList()
      .pipe(map(arr => arr.filter(r => r.active == true)))
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.users = result;
      });
  }
```

> the Delete Function

```
  deleteEmployee(id: number) {
    this.userService.deleteUser(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.reloadData();
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

> User service method:

```
getUsersList(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
```

}

> the Html code:

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-plain" data-aos="fade-right">
          <div class="card-header " style="background-color: #09c0a3;">
            <h4 class="card-title mt-0" style="color:white;">
              Tableau des Utilisateurs
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead class="">
                  <th>
                    ID
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Nom
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Prénom
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Email
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Role
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Actions
                  </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let u of users">
                    <td>
                      {{ u.id }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {{ u.nom }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {{ u.prenom }}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ u.email }}</td>
                    <td>
                      <span *ngFor="let r of u.roles">{{ r }} </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <button
                        class="btn btn-danger "
                        (click)="deleteEmployee(u.id)"
                      >
                        Supprimer
                      </button>

                      <button class="btn " (click)="OnEdit(u.id)">
                        Details
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[a photo to make things more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0N4f.png)

[as you see in this second image the user has been deleted ({deleted:true}) but still display on the page and an error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT2xZ.png)

Comment: Post contents of `this.userService.getUsersList()`

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: @NicholasK this line      " .pipe(map(arr => arr.filter(r => r.active == true)))"

Comment: The issue is with the null or undefined value returned from service, added the answer below with explanation.

Comment: Comment out that .pipe line and do a console.log of the response. You can then verify what response is being returned.

Comment: thank you guys it works, especially @Prince you're right , thank you

Comment: @Mensi98 This suggests that your API returns a null instead of an empty array when there are no users. It's always worth checking your network tab for the actual response first.

Comment: @KurtHamilton u're right thank youu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the service is returning `null` or `undefined` value and your code is not handling those values.

Either sanitize your service so that it return always a valid value else modify your code in component class. Use below code:

```
.pipe(map(arr => arr && arr.length && arr.filter(r => r.active == true)))
```

Check the validity of data before filtering

Comment: it works @Prince but , it should be like this .pipe(map(arr => arr && arr.filter(r => r.active == true))) without arr.length or it will occurs an error like " cannot read property length of null" thank you anyway

Comment: ohh, it means we need to add one more check, updating my answer. Thanks!

Comment: i delete the .length and it works as well without errors.

Comment: It will work untill your arr object is an array or (null/undefined/0/fasle/"")